# In app Purchases Test payments

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have currently added my application in Google play as alpha release to test in app products and it was a success.
But my point is I have generated emails saying you have made a purchase.But in the message from they saying this is a testing payment you will not be charged.So will i be charge if they really consider this as an payment.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing payments will still have an email generated with an order number, payment type and company you have purchased from.

The body of the email will be exactly the same as a legitimate purchase, however the email subject will start with "Test:".

Also you can check if a purchase will be charged by logging into your [Google wallet merchant center](https://wallet.google.com/merchant) and viewing the list of sales. Test orders are flagged as such here.